# Difference between HibernateTransactionManager and OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

From the docs - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateTransactionManager.html

HibernateTransactionManager - Binds a Hibernate Session from the specified factory to the thread, potentially allowing for one thread-bound Session per factory

OpenSessionInViewFilter - This filter makes Hibernate Sessions available via the current thread, which will be autodetected by transaction managers.

What is the difference between both of them and at what scenarios should they be used ?

Answer (score -1):

```
OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

Now when you are using `OpenSessionInViewFilter`, by default the session's flush mode is set to NEVER. So when you try to save something in your action using hibenate and commit it, it wont be reflected in your database. To solve this you need to flush the session in your action class or extend `OpenSessionInViewFilter` and override `closeSession(Session session, SessionFactory sessionFactory)`.

Now it is also possible that you are maintaining a single transaction for per request. In your action you edit the attributes of a object and update it using `session.update(object)`. But it is not yet commited as some other processing is remaining. At the same time, some other request is invoking a action which tries to retrieve the object which you were updating. Since the object is not yet commited the other request will get the old object. To solve this you need to begin a transaction before you load object and commit the transaction after you update the object. So that as soon as the object is `saved/updated` it is commited. With this there can be many transaction in single user request but only one session.

The `OpenSessionInView` pattern only guarantees that the session is open during one single thread execution.
When the page has been rendered and has been returned to the browser, the session gets closed by the filter.

So subsequent requests (e.g. navigation request) require another new session which will be opened by the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. But as the "old" person object is not connected to the "new" session, it is considered as disconnected object which's references cannot be loaded lazily.

Comment: You are actually wrong. The flush mode is set to `manual` not never. If you use Spring's transaction support the `HibernateTransactionManager` will set it to `AUTO` again (resetting it after the commit). So flushing will happen. If it isn't it is a mistake in your configuration/setup of your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum
from class
NOTE: This filter will by default not flush the Hibernate Session, with the flush mode set to FlushMode.NEVER. It assumes to be used in combination with service layer transactions that care for the flushing: The active transaction manager will temporarily change the flush mode to FlushMode.AUTO during a read-write transaction, with the flush mode reset to FlushMode.NEVER at the end of each transaction. If you intend to use this filter without transactions, consider changing the default flush mode (through the "flushMode" property).